# To multiply before taking the second derivative, or not?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If I have a first derivative of $$5(3x^2-11)^4\cdot (6x)$$ should I multiply by the 6x to get $$30x(3x^2-11)^3$$ first and then take the second derivative or not? Does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to multiply the 6 and the 5 in the end so you might as well do it up front and get it out of the way.  The meat of the problem is going to be using the product rule in either case.  (You also need to fix the exponent outside the parentheses in the second version of your expression - it changed from a 4 to a 3.)

Comment: Ok, so fixing the 3 and putting it back as a four I would then use the product rule with 30x as f and (3x^2-11)^4 as g in f ' g + g ' f?

Comment: That would be the right approach.  You could make it even easier by letting g be just the x and f be the (3x^2 - 11)^4, using the product rule then multiplying the final result by 30.  In other words, D_x(30 * f * g) = 30 D_x(f * g).

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot.